# Link to open external link on wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Actually i am developing a plugin on wordpress where user can given link as input link google.com on a text field and it save on database but in front end it shows like http://my-host/test/Demo/demo-1/google.com. I want to only google.com not the full part.

Comment: anyone know to reply quick

Comment: What did you try so far ? May you share your code that we can help you ?

Comment: so what exactly are you trying to do, what exactly have you tried to achieve this and what exactly is your problem? and why exactly are you so impatient?

Comment: You will not receive a "quick reply" if you are not even able to explain your issue in a way that we can understand. What does "input link google.com" actually mean? And what is "but it takes as http://my-host/test/Demo/demo-1/google.com.I" meant to express? Sorry, but it is in your interest to ask your question such that others can actually understand it. You just dump a few words here and expect us to magically _guess_ what you might be looking for.

Comment: check the above updated the issue

Comment: This issue has been solved